# Extracting More than 5 reviews from Google places/Map Api

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to the review data for different places in my locality. Is there any way that i can extract more than 5 review results as the api is returning only 5 reviews per place.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the owner of the place in Google My Business you can get all reviews via Google My Business API:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/#collection-v3accountslocationsreviews

Otherwise you can only access to 5 reviews via Places API. There is a feature request to get more than 5 reviews in Places API:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825957

Feel free to star this feature request to add your vote and subscribe to updates from Google.